# Scripting to remove specific characters in ArcGIS 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am unable to find in the Help / Resource the script if there is one, to remove certain characters in a column. Example  MPRR-BLK39-T4S-29-01. I want to get rid of T4S for 25 parcels. Instead of going to each individual parcel and manually edit, is there a certain script that will delete out "T4S"?

Comment: You could export your table to a csv and make the edit in something like notepad++ or excel doing a simple "Find and Replace".  I would suggest at this point, if you have exported all columns, to delete them all except for the one you have edited and a column that holds a unique identifier for each record.
You could then join this csv file back to your dataset in ArcGIS using your  unique identifier field and either delete the original column (the one with the incorrect values) or use the Field Calculator to update the original column with the values from the newly imported column.

Comment: I added the above as a comment rather than an answer as I didn't provide a scripting solution, which is what the OP was asking for.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea too as I always have done that method prior to doing any joins.  Good idea as a roundabout way.  Thank you.

Comment: Brilliant.  Will add as answer now so others can search for it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a scripting solution, more of a workaround...

You could export your table to a csv and make the edit in something like notepad++ or excel doing a simple "Find and Replace".

I would suggest at this point, if you have exported all columns, to delete them all except for the one you have edited and a column that holds a unique identifier for each record.

You could then join this csv file back to your dataset in ArcGIS using your unique identifier field and either delete the original column (the one with the incorrect values) or use the Field Calculator to update the original column with the values from the newly imported column.

Answer (score 4):

I assume the dataset is an ESRI format.  If so, you can use [arcpy.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm).

```
import arcpy

ds = r'path_to_dataset'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ds, ['Field1']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if 'T4S' in row[0]:
            row[0] = row[0].replace('T4S', '')
            cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

Comment: I'm not a programmer type, I just add that to Field Calculator right?

Comment: No, you should copy this to a Python file (.py) and run the module (press F5   with the .py file open).  Or, you can copy that to the Python window in ArcMap.